# Access Get subfolder of shared folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get the meetings from an outlook shared sub folder, but I have no idea why the code below is not working..

```
Public Sub getCalendarData(calendar_name As String, sDate As Date, eDate As Date, Optional recurItem As Boolean = True)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oAppointments As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim ItemsCal As Outlook.Items
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim fldCalendar As Outlook.Folder
    Dim iCalendar As Integer
    Dim nmsNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objDummy As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient

    'Set objects

    Set oOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set nmsNameSpace = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objDummy = oOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set objRecip = objDummy.Recipients.Add("shared calendar name")
    objRecip.Resolve

    'Set filter to grab items by date range
    strFilter = "[Start] >= " _
    & "'" & sDate & "'" _
    & " AND [End] <= " _
    & "'" & eDate & "'"

    With ItemsCal
        .Sort "[Start]"
        .IncludeRecurrences = recurItem
    End With

    If objRecip.Resolved Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar).Folders("sub_calendar_name")

        If Not fldCalendar Is Nothing Then
            Set ItemsCal = fldCalendar.Items
            If Not ItemsCal Is Nothing Then
                For Each oAppointmentItem In ItemsCal.Restrict(strFilter)
                    Set objItem = oAppointmentItem
                    With oAppointmentItem
                        iCalendar = getSegmentIDByName(calendar_name)
                        meeting_id = insertAppointment(iCalendar, .Start, .End, scrubData(.Subject), scrubData(.Location), Format(.Start, "Long Time"), .duration, .Body)
                        Call GetAttendeeList(meeting_id, objItem, .Recipients)
                    End With
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Garbage cleanup
    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oAppoinments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOL = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    'MsgBox "Error: " & Err & " | " & Error(Err)
    'Whenever error occurs, skip to next
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

If I only use `Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)` it will give me the shared calendar items, but not the subfolder calendar items

Could someone point me trough?

Thank you!

Comment: What about `nmsNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar).Folders("Folder Name")` ?

Comment: 'Folder name' or 'sub_calendar_name' are the same thing..

Comment: Yes, Have you tried updating it with sub-folder name?

Comment: My folder name is SharedCalendar and the sub_calendar_name is the same, it was just an example, in the .Folders("") it can be any name of folder.. it will not work at all

Comment: Fix the following `Set objRecip = objDummy.Recipients.Add("shared calendar name")` To `Set objRecip = nmsNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Owner's Name or email address")` see if that helps

Comment: Can you put it as an answer? Just to be able to mark it as correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the following `Set objRecip = objDummy.Recipients.Add("shared calendar name")` To `Set objRecip = nmsNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Owner's Name or email address")` see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for your support fixing the access to subfolders, but right now, after I was able 2 days ago to access them, I am not able anymore, using the same code.. Do you know what could be the reason?